# Is it possible to spoof the MAC address of a wireless adapter so that Windows sees the spoofed MAC as the physical?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I know that its possible to spoof a MAC address out to a network, but is it possible to spoof the address so that Windows and applications running in Windows see a spoofed address as the physical address for the network card?

Answer (score 0):

Some freeware tools like [mac address](http://www.zokali.com/win7-mac-address-changer/) changer may help you to do this, From their website

> Win7 MAC Address changer is a simple freeware windows program which
>   can change the MAC (Media Access Control) Address of wired and
>   wireless network adapters (Not routers). Win7 MAC Address Changer was
>   developed to be a very simple utility. It’s usage is straightforward
>   just select the network adapter (virtual and loopback adapters are not
>   show as it is not need), select your operating system, enter or
>   generate MAC Address and just hit the change button, it is that
>   simple! There are practically many uses of changing the mac address
>   (physical address) such as troubleshooting network problems, software
>   and hardware components, to hide the your identity in a network.

[image]

Comment: The problem with programs like that though is that they just change the mac address that the computer is broadcasting, not the physical mac address that windows sees

Comment: @Ethan personally tried this one and working fine in my lan anyways check it out and let me know if it doesnt worked

Comment: When you go to the command line and run the command "getmac" does it show the spoofed address or the original physical address? Every time I try to change it it still only shows the original physical address